# Concatenating field values into one "word" in rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is it possible to concatenate all values of a field into one "word" so it can be displayed in one textBox of the rdlc report. If not, is there some other way to display entire field in one textbox?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552292/how-to-concatenate-values-in-rdlc-expression

Comment: No, I already saw this post. In that case the user wanted to concatenate members of different fields, I need to concatenate members of the same field (for instance all first names of persons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `ReportParameter` with multiple values.

However I never used it and I didn't found any article/blog post/forum that exaplain step by step how to accomplish your task.

[Maybe this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ceabc828-d389-45bd-9ad0-580cc857686c/) but they are speaking about SSRS

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, but on the application level, by adding another column into the DataTable and into putting the concatenated value in each row of that column. That way, I was able to simply group by the concatenated value (and some other values) and got the correct result. Thanks anyway