# How to add a pound symbol(£) before the formula in textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting, rdlc, formula

Here is my piece of formula in a textbox

```
=Fields!TotalCost2.Value+Fields!TotalCost1.Value
```

Now i want to add a £ in the formula so that the output will be

```
£ 300.00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set TextBox.Format = "C2" it will display the symbol declared in your regional settings ("C") formatted with 2 decimal digits ("2").

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to type in the alt code for the pound symbol(`£`).

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> +  <kbd>6</kbd>  +  <kbd>3</kbd>

Then you can enter the following into your formula:

```
="£ " & Fields!TotalCost2.Value+Fields!TotalCost1.Value
```

I am assuming that this will be statically declared, and it does not need to change across currencies.

It's the same as any concatenation like in this question [How to concatenate values in RDLC expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552292/299327)